# Convert zipped JPGs into PDFs

Tags: linux, shell, pdf, zip, converters

I have a folder with a lot of **ZIP** files. Each one contains scanned pages of a document which I need convert to **PDF**. The result of *x.zip* and *y.zip* need to be *x.pd*f and *y.pdf*.

I read [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1267482) and saw that `convert -compress Zip *.jpg output.pdf` makes JPGs to a single PDF, but mine is zipped.
Is there a one line command for **Linux** (Ubuntu 15.10) that I can use to accomplish this for all files?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made one in **Python**. Isn't the best way, but works. I needed something like that, but simpler and faster.

```
from os import listdir, system, getcwd
from os.path import isfile, join
mypath = getcwd()
onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f))]

system('mkdir tmp')

for f in onlyfiles:
    g = f.split('.')[0]
    system('rm tmp/*')
    system('unzip "%s" -d tmp' % f)
    system('convert tmp/* "%s.pdf"' % g)

system('rm -rf tmp')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can unzip archives with the unzip utility and then reference them with the convert command. It's a cheated one liner (two commands), but it works:

```
unzip \*.zip; convert -compress Zip *.jpg output.pdf
```

This unzip all of your files into the current directory and then load all of the .jpg extension files and put them on separate pages in a single PDF named output.pdf

Comment: I want something like that, but working... I don't know much about params in pipe commands.

Comment: I updated the answer after actually testing this on my machine. Try the updated answer and see if that works for you.

Comment: The pdf filename must be the zip filename, like file1.zip to file1.pdf, this way the filename will be always output.pdf.